# Initialize an array of object with unknown keys in a better way using es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an object as follows:

```
{
    "counts": {
        "created_by_ref": {
            "00f5c303-32c0-4f5f-ac61-bf6577a8f4ed": 1,
            "0dde2de1-7951-45b1-8bf3-013f8dbfc4ae": 1
        },
        "file.hashes.MD5": {
            "qqq": 200
        },
        "ipv4_addr.value": {
            "127.0.0.1": 200,
            "192.168.1.10": 200
        },
        "network_traffic.dst_port": {
            "xxx": 200
        },
        "network_traffic.dst_ref.resolves_to_refs.value": {
            "yyy": 200
        },
        "network_traffic.dst_ref.value": {
            "rrr": 200
        }
    }
}
```

I need to initialize all the values to 0 as follows:

```
{
    "counts": {
        "created_by_ref": {
            "00f5c303-32c0-4f5f-ac61-bf6577a8f4ed": 0,
            "0dde2de1-7951-45b1-8bf3-013f8dbfc4ae": 0
        },
        "file.hashes.MD5": {
            "qqq": 0
        },
        "ipv4_addr.value": {
            "127.0.0.1": 0,
            "192.168.1.10": 0
        },
        "network_traffic.dst_port": {
            "xxx": 0
        },
        "network_traffic.dst_ref.resolves_to_refs.value": {
            "yyy": 0
        },
        "network_traffic.dst_ref.value": {
            "rrr": 0
        }
    }
}
```

and all the keys except count is unknown and dynamically changing so cannot be hard code.
What I did is:

```
  for (const key in getSearchDataAllCounts) {
    if (getSearchDataAllCounts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      Object.keys(getSearchDataAllCounts[key]).forEach((innerkey) => {
        getSearchDataAllCounts[key][innerkey] = 0;
      });
    }
  }
```

But I really think there is a better way doing it in ES6. Is there any improvement I can make to make it more es6 compatible and also do it with one loop preferebly?

Comment: I'm curious why `for-in` for one loop but `Object.keys().forEach` for the other...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so two Object.keys() inside each other?

Comment: Right, which avoids the need for the `hasOwnProperty` check. It's just, it looks like an intentional choice, using `for-in` for the outer loop and `Object.keys().forEach` for the inner one. If it's not intentional, no worries, I just thought it might be. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just saw the answer thanks  . So we cannot do it with one loop right?

Comment: You can do it with what *looks* like one loop, but is really nested loops like the above. I'll add that to the answer. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a million will wait for your update in the answer. I am learning a lot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES2015+ doesn't really give you much to improve that code, other than [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
for (const entry of Object.values(getSearchDataAllCounts.counts)) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(entry)) {
    entry[key] = 0;
  }
}
```

In a comment you asked:

> So we cannot do it with one loop right?

You can do it with what *looks* like one loop, but is really nested loops like the above (more loops, in fact):

```
for (const [key, entry] of Object.entries(getSearchDataAllCounts.counts)) {
    getSearchDataAllCounts.counts[key] = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.keys(entry).map(key => [key, 0])
    );
}
```

That uses [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of `[key, value]` pairs for the outer object, then replaces that object with a new object we create by

- Getting its keys
- Mapping them to `[key, 0]` entries
- Using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object from those entries

There's an important difference there, though: It creates **new** objects to store on the properties of the outermost object. The first one just updates the properties of the existing objects.

Comment: Also can explain if there is a specific reason your outer loop is over value rather than key? what if we have two unique key with the same value?

Comment: @Learner - That doesn't matter, we'll see the value twice. But if you might really have two properties that refer to the **same** object, the second solution will replace them with two distinct objects.

Comment: @Learner - Apologies, I'm getting called away. If you have further follow-up questions, I'll answer them when I'm back.

Comment: Thanks should I not change the first loop to: for (const entry of Object.values(getSearchDataAllCounts.counts)) {. ???

Comment: @Learner - Doh! Yes. :-) Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need ES6. Using JSON replacer, u can do it on the tree traversing.

> **Util**

```
const zero = obj =>
   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (_, v) => (typeof v === "object" ? v : 0)));
```

console.log(zero(d));

> **How to use**

```
console.log(zero(d));
```

```js
var d = {
  counts: {
    created_by_ref: {
      "00f5c303-32c0-4f5f-ac61-bf6577a8f4ed": 1,
      "0dde2de1-7951-45b1-8bf3-013f8dbfc4ae": 1
    },
    "file.hashes.MD5": {
      qqq: 200
    },
    "ipv4_addr.value": {
      "127.0.0.1": 200,
      "192.168.1.10": 200
    },
    "network_traffic.dst_port": {
      xxx: 200
    },
    "network_traffic.dst_ref.resolves_to_refs.value": {
      yyy: 200
    },
    "network_traffic.dst_ref.value": {
      rrr: 200
    }
  }
};
const zero = obj => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (_, v) => (typeof v === "object" ? v : 0)));
console.log(zero(d));
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```